# Replacement of piston rings

Tags: engine, toyota

Can I go uphill just after replacing the piston rings? 
If after replacing the piston rings, I see shortage of oil every morning, what could be the cause?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If there is a shortage of oil each morning, were is it going? Is it on the ground? Is it in the coolant? Is it being burned (smoke from the exhaust)? These are things we could not possibly know. After an engine rebuild, there are many different reasons you are losing oil.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I go uphill just after replacing the piston rings?

Yes, you can. You should be gentle for the first 1000 km or so, and have an additional oil-change after that.

The first 50 km should already been done by your mechanic to break it in and oil changed after that.

> If after replacing the piston rings, I see shortage of oil every
>   morning, what could be the cause?

There could be a lot of causes. As replacing the piston rings requires a disassembly of the engine the could be:

- Seals not tight/leaking: Oil pan, cylinder head, rocker cover, crankshaft, oil-lines (oil-cooler, turbo etc. whatever your car has)
- Piston ring replacement done inadequately. Head and block should have been checked for any warping and flattened if necessary. Cylinders should have been honed, if there was some wear. Pistons should have been checked and replaced with oversize ones if necessary.

It takes some time for the piston rings to set and seal properly, but it should not be to the extent that you have to refill every day.

You first order should be to check where the oil goes. If it goes out the back you probably have a problem with either sealing of the piston rings or the head gasket. Watch for blueish smoke out of the exhaust.  Else you´ll find some oily spots on your motor - reseal.

Answer (score 0):

You should treat the engine gently for the first few miles : if by uphill you mean a hill climb competition then no, if you mean a normal trip to the shops with good / appropriate use of the gears if it is a manual ( the lack of info does not help) ie don’t labour the engine or rev too high, then it will be fine.

As to the loss of oil - every morning? And how much is lost? Is there any evidence under the vehicle after it stands overnight? If there is - is there a pipe loose?

More info sbout engine, transmission year would help.